# How do I remember method so I can use it back when server restarts?

Tags: java, database

I am writing RaspberryPi program for executing tasks at given time. I wrote TaskManager that keeps all tasks in synchronized Map (awaitingTasks) and manage them. One of it's methods is

addInTimeTasks(...)

```
public static int addInTimeTask(Callable task,  DateTime time) {
    synchronized (awaitingTasks) {
        final int id = assignNewId();
        awaitingTasks.put(id, scheduledThreadPool.schedule(new CallableTask(task, new CallableTask.MyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                awaitingTasks.remove(id);
            }
        }), TimeDiffCalc.secToDate(time), TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        return id;
    }
}
```

as you can see Task (thinking of making it class if it has more attributes) have its own ID, Date and method that it executes.

I want to handle situation when server restarts and all in time tasks simply dissapear. I was thinking about holding Tasks in database. I can hold TaskID and Date but how do I determine method that given task should execute?

I like flexablity of this method cuz I can make any method in-time executable.
For example here is method from RGBLed class (which have mutltiple methods that can be executed in time)

```
public int lightLed(final LedColor color, DateTime dateTime){
    return TaskManager.addInTimeTask(new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            //here is code that makes led lighting
            return null;
        }
    },dateTime);
}
```

What came into my mind was to assign to every method ID, and then get method by id but I dont think it is passible.

I ll bet that were many questions with similar problem but I can not simply find them. I can not specify question properly (So please change it)

Thanks!

Comment: You want to persist your data. Could be int a serialized text file to keep it simple, or a Database. Insert your tasks on it, and flag them (or just delete) when they are finished.

When the system boots, first thing is to load the array with the file/database tasks.

Comment: I dont think we understood each other. Every class have multiple methods that can be executed in time. When i add a Task i override a method. And problem is that i need to have some handler to THIS particular method saved somewhere. So when servers back it ll recover proper method.

Comment: When you serialize, you will be saving the class type, then you can reach your method. You have to save the class type, so it will be possible to re-create it.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing two problems. That one that you describe can be fixed "easily". You see, you know that you want to call specific methods.

Methods have names. Names are ... strings. So, you could simply store that name as string; and when you have some object in front of you, you can use Java reflection means to invoke a particular method.

The other problem is: persisting your objects might not be that easy. If I get your examples right, you are mostly dealing with anonymous inner classes. And yes, objects of such classes can be serialized too, but not as "easy" or "without thought" as normal classes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465641/serialization-of-anonymous-class-in-java) for example).

So, my suggestions:

1. Don't use inner classes; but ordinary classes (although that might affect the "layout" of existing code to a great degree); serialize objects of those classes
2. Together with serialized object, remember name (and probably the arguments you need) so you can call methods by name

Probably it would make sense to create a class specifically for that purpose; containing two fields (the actual object to serialized, and the name of the method to call on that).